# Warning while using file_get_contents

Tags: php

I used the following code.

$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.google.co.in/');
echo $homepage;

But it display the following warning message

Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.google.co.in/) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in /home/web/cron/sample.php on line 47

Answer (score 1):

1. Check setting in php.ini allow_url_fopen
2. Check your DNS settings.
3. Check firewall settings

Comment: I dont know how and what to check in the DNS and firewall setting pls provide some information about that.

Comment: Look at http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch18_:_Configuring_DNS for DNS

Comment: Look at http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-scanning-network-for-open-ports.html fro scanning opened ports